# SSRS Date Parameters - Setting Date B = Date A whenever Date A is changed

Tags: reporting-services

I am looking into a query from one of our users regarding the behaviour of date pickers on their report.

They have asked that when they enter a date in Date Paramater A that this is then duplicated in Date Parameter B.

I can achieve this when the report is first run by given Date Parameter A no default value (so it has to be chosen by the user) and seet Date Parameter B's default value via an expression to "=Parameters!StartDate.Value".

The question though is wether or not I can recreate this when Parameter A is updated. Therefore if they run the report once and then decide they need to choose another date. Can I set Date Parameter B to refresh each time Date Parameter A is changed?

**E.G**

Report is opened

Date Parameter A is set to 02/12/2013.
Date Parameter B now defaults to 02/12/2013.
Search is performed

A second search is required so, without closing the report the user changes the date in Date Parameter A

Date Parameter A is now set to 05/12/2013
Date Paramater B still says 02/12/2013 - can I somehow make this auto refresh to match Date Parameter A if Date Parameter A changes?

***EDIT:*** Thanks to Kalim for pointing this out but it must also be noted that although I would like Date Parameter B to default to the new value selected by Date Parameter A, dates greater than that selected for Date Parameter A must also be available in case they wish to widen the range of dates.

Hopefully that is clear, but if any further information is required then please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: If you double-click on a report parameter in the designer view, and then go to the 'Advanced' options, there are options for when to 'Refresh data when this parameter changes'. Perhaps changing these setting for one or both parameters will help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the "Available Values" to the value of the first date parameter.

Select "Available Values" then select the "Specify values" option. Add a value and edit the expression of the value. Set this to the same expression you used in your default value expression.

Hope that makes sense!

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi Kalim, thanks for your answer and pointing out the missing information in my question! Unfortunately this won't work as whilst I want Date Parameter B to default to Date Parameter A they may wish to select some date in the future so future dates must be available too

Comment: Not so sure i understand exactly what you mean. When Date A changes Date B needs to change as well.. correct? But date B should still be independent of date A? Edit: Actually i see the problem. Once Date A is set date B changes but you can no longer select a date for Date B using the Datepicker.

Comment: To get the best out of SSRS though you might want to look into building your own custom prompt pages. This would be a breeze to do using javascript/jquery :) The default SSRS prompt bar is very limited in functionality and you will find more than one occasion where something simple turns out to be complex to implement.